# Mathematically compute a simple graphics pipeline

Tags: math, graphics, 3d

I am trying to do / understand all the basic mathematical computations needed in the graphics pipeline to render a simple 2D image from a 3D scene description like VRML. Is there a good example of the steps needed, like **model transformation** (object coordinates to world coordinates), **view transformation** (from world coordinate to view coordinate), **calculation of vertex normals** for lighting, **clipping**, **calculating the screen coordinates** of objects inside the view frustum and **creating the 2D projection** to calculate the individual pixels with colors.

Comment: What kind of example are you looking for? One which does all these steps for an explicit scene? Or ain an explicit programming framework? Or which gives a list of steps like the ones you posted?

Comment: I am looking for an example for an explicit scene which shows all the computations and explains the math. I want to understand the math steps for rendering :-)

Comment: [POV ray tracer](http://www.povray.org/) is opensource.

Comment: @FelixCastor - thank you for your reply but I am looking for the mathematical calculations and examples not for a software :-)

Comment: This is for robots but it uses the same principles of homogeneous transformation matrices.  [Geometric Transforms](http://planning.cs.uiuc.edu/ch3.pdf) pg 98 and beyond.  Might be useful.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I am used to **OpenGL** style render math so I stick to it (all the renders use almost the same math)

First some therms to explain:

1. **Transform matrix**

Represents a coordinate system in **3D** space

```
    double m[16]; // it is 4x4 matrix stored as 1 dimensional array for speed
    m[0]=xx; m[4]=yx; m[ 8]=zx; m[12]=x0;
    m[1]=xy; m[5]=yy; m[ 9]=zy; m[13]=y0;
    m[2]=xz; m[6]=yz; m[10]=zz; m[14]=z0;
    m[3]= 0; m[7]= 0; m[11]= 0; m[15]= 1;
```

where:

- `X(xx,xy,xz)` is unit vector of `X` axis in **GCS** (global coordinate system)
- `Y(yx,yy,yz)` is unit vector of `Y` axis in **GCS**
- `Z(zx,zy,zz)` is unit vector of `Z` axis in **GCS**
- `P(x0,y0,z0)` is origin of represented coordinate system in **GCS**

Transformation matrix is used to transform coordinates between **GCS** and **LCS** (local coordinate system)

- **GCS `->` LCS:**  `Al = Ag * m;`
- **GCS `<-` LCS:**  `Ag = Al * (m^-1);`
- `Al (x,y,z,w=1)` is **3D** point in **LCS** ... in homogenous coordinates
- `Ag (x,y,z,w=1)` is **3D** point in **GCS** ... in homogenous coordinates

homogenous coordinate `w=1` is added so we can multiply **3D** vector by **4x4** matrix

- `m` transformation matrix
- `m^-1` inverse transformation matrix

In most cases is `m` orthonormal which means `X,Y,Z` vectors are **perpendicular** to each other and with **unit size** this can be used for restoration of matrix accuracy after rotations,translations,etc ...

For more info see [Understanding 4x4 homogenous transform matrices](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28084380/2521214)

2. **Render matrices**

There are usually used these matrices:

- `model` - represents actual rendered object coordinate system
- `view` - represents camera coordinate system (`Z` axis is the view direction)
- `modelview` - model and view multiplied together
- `normal` - the same as `modelview` but `x0,y0,z0 = 0` for normal vector computations
- `texture` - manipulate texture coordinates for easy texture animation and effect usually an unit matrix
- `projection` - represent projections of camera view ( [perspective](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24009436/2521214) ,ortho,...) it should not include any rotations or translations its more like Camera sensor calibration instead (otherwise fog and other effects will fail ...)

3. **The rendering math**

To render **3D** scene you need **2D** rendering routines like draw **2D** textured triangle ... The render converts **3D** scene data to **2D** and renders it. There are more techniques out there but the most usual is use of **boundary model representation** + **boundary rendering** (surface only) The **3D `->` 2D** conversion is done by projection (orthogonal or perspective) and Z-buffer or Z-sorting.

- **Z-buffer** is easy and native to now-days gfx HW
- **Z-sorting**  is done by **CPU** instead so its slower and need additional memory but it is necessary for correct transparent surfaces rendering.

**So the pipeline is as this:**

1. **obtain actual rendered data from model**

- **Vertex** `v`
- **Normal** `n`
- **Texture** coord `t`
- **Color,Fog** coord, etc...

2. **convert it to appropriate space**

- `v=projection*view*model*v`   ... camera space + projection
- `n=normal*n`                  ... global space
- `t=texture*t`                 ... texture space

3. **clip data to screen**

This step is not necessary but prevent to render of screen stuff for speed and also face culling is usually done here. If normal vector of rendered 'triangle' is opposite then the polygon winding rule set then ignore 'triangle'

4. **render the 3D/2D data**

use only `v.x,v.y` coordinates for screen rendering and v.z for z-buffer test/value also here goes the perspective division for perspective projections

- `v.x/=v.z,vy/=v.z`

**Z-buffer** works like this: **Z-buffer** (`zed`) is **2D** array with the same size (resolution) as screen (`scr`). Any **pixel** `scr[y][x]` is rendered only `if (zed[y][x]>=z)` in that case `scr[y][x]=color; zed[y][x]=z;` The if condition can be different (it is changeable)

In case of using triangles or higher primitives for rendering The resulting **2D** primitives are converted to pixels in process called rasterization for example like this:

- [Algorithm to fill triangle](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39062479/2521214)

**For more clarity here is how it looks like:**

[image: 3D rendering]

**[Notes]**

Transformation matrices are multiplicative so if you need transform `N` points by `M` matrices you can create single `matrix = m1*m2*...mM` and convert `N` points by this resulting `matrix` only (for speed). Sometimes are used `3x3` transform matrix + `shift vector` instead of `4x4` matrix. it is faster in some cases but you cannot multiply more transformations together so easy. For transformation matrix manipulation look for basic operations like Rotate or Translate there are also matrices for rotations inside **LCS** which are more suitable for human control input but these are not native to renders like **OpenGL** or **DirectX**. (because they use inverse matrix)

Now all the above stuff was for standard polygonal rendering (surface boundary representation of objects). There are also other renderers out there like Volumetric rendering or (Back)Ray-tracers and hybrid methods. Also the scene can have any dimensionality not just 3D. Here some related **QAs** covering these topics:

- [GLSL 3D Volumetric back raytracer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48092685/2521214)
- [GLSL 3D Mesh back raytracer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45140313/2521214)
- [2D Doom/Wolfenstein techniques](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47251071/2521214)
- [4D Rendering techniques](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44970550/2521214)
- [Comanche Voxel space ray casting](https://github.com/s-macke/VoxelSpace)

Answer (score 0):

You can have a look [Chapter 15](http://cgpp.net/file/cgpp3e_ch15.pdf) from the book *Computer Graphics: Principles and Practice - Third Edition* by Hughes et al. That chapter

> Derives the ray-casting and rasterization algorithms and then builds
>   the complete source code for a software ray-tracer, software
>   rasterizer, and hardware-accelerated rasterization renderer.