# Implementing integer 1/z depth buffer

Tags: c++, graphics, 3d, rendering, depth-buffer

I am trying to adapt the code from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65460132/how-to-hide-invisible-elements-of-the-3d-drawing/65664918#65664918) to use 1/z depth buffer and here is my attempt

```
/* g++ trig.cpp -o trig -lSDL2 */

#include <algorithm>

#define SDL_MAIN_HANDLED
#include <SDL2/SDL.h>

#define SCREEN_WIDTH  600
#define SCREEN_HEIGHT 400

// TODO make an array of values to be interpolated
// TODO uv texture mapping
typedef struct
{
    int x, y, z;
    int zInv; // 1/z
    uint8_t r, g, b;
    int u, v;
} Point2D;

constexpr int SIZE = SCREEN_WIDTH * SCREEN_HEIGHT;

uint32_t pixels[SIZE];
int zDepth[SIZE];

void SetPixel(int x, int y, int zInv, uint8_t r, uint8_t g, uint8_t b)
{
    int offset = y * SCREEN_WIDTH + x;

    if (zDepth[offset] < zInv)
    {
        zDepth[offset] = zInv;
        pixels[offset] = (255 << 24) | (r << 16) | (g << 8) | b;
    }
}

int ContourX[SCREEN_HEIGHT][2]; // min X and max X for every horizontal line within the triangle
int ContourZ[SCREEN_HEIGHT][2]; // 1/z
int ContourR[SCREEN_HEIGHT][2]; // red value for every horizontal line
int ContourG[SCREEN_HEIGHT][2]; // green value for every horizontal line
int ContourB[SCREEN_HEIGHT][2]; // blue value for every horizontal line

// Scans a side of a triangle setting min X and max X in ContourX[][] (same for ContourR, ContourG, and ContourB) using the Bresenham's
void TriangleLine(const Point2D& p0, const Point2D& p1)
{
    // DDA variables
    int kx, ky, kz, kr, kg, kb; // step directions
    int dx, dy, dz, dr, dg, db; // abs delta
    kx = 0; dx = p1.x - p0.x; if (dx > 0) kx = 1; if (dx < 0) { kx = -1; dx = -dx; }
    ky = 0; dy = p1.y - p0.y; if (dy > 0) ky = 1; if (dy < 0) { ky = -1; dy = -dy; }
    kz = 0; dz = p1.zInv - p0.zInv; if (dz > 0) kz = 1; if (dz < 0) { kz = -1; dz = -dz; }
    kr = 0; dr = p1.r - p0.r; if (dr > 0) kr = 1; if (dr < 0) { kr = -1; dr = -dr; }
    kg = 0; dg = p1.g - p0.g; if (dg > 0) kg = 1; if (dg < 0) { kg = -1; dg = -dg; }
    kb = 0; db = p1.b - p0.b; if (db > 0) kb = 1; if (db < 0) { kb = -1; db = -db; }

    int n;
    n = dx;
    if (n < dy) n = dy;
    if (n < dz) n = dz;
    if (n < dr) n = dr;
    if (n < dg) n = dg;
    if (n < db) n = db;
    if (!n) n = 1;

    // target buffer according to ky direction
    int target; if (ky > 0) target = 0; else target = 1;

    // integer DDA line start point
    int x = p0.x;
    int y = p0.y;
    int z = p0.zInv;
    int r = p0.r;
    int g = p0.g;
    int b = p0.b;

    // fix endpoints just to be sure (wrong division constants by +/-1 can cause that last point is missing)
    ContourX[p0.y][target] = p0.x;
    ContourZ[p0.y][target] = p0.zInv;
    ContourR[p0.y][target] = p0.r;
    ContourG[p0.y][target] = p0.g;
    ContourB[p0.y][target] = p0.b;

    ContourX[p1.y][target] = p1.x;
    ContourZ[p1.y][target] = p1.zInv;
    ContourR[p1.y][target] = p1.r;
    ContourG[p1.y][target] = p1.g;
    ContourB[p1.y][target] = p1.b;

    int cx, cy, cz, cr, cg, cb, i;
    for (cx = cy = cz = cr = cg = cb = n, i = 0; i < n; ++i)
    {
        ContourX[y][target] = x;
        ContourZ[y][target] = z;
        ContourR[y][target] = r;
        ContourG[y][target] = g;
        ContourB[y][target] = b;

        cx -= dx; if (cx <= 0){ cx += n; x += kx; }
        cy -= dy; if (cy <= 0){ cy += n; y += ky; }
        cz -= dz; if (cz <= 0){ cz += n; z += kz; }
        cr -= dr; if (cr <= 0){ cr += n; r += kr; }
        cg -= dg; if (cg <= 0){ cg += n; g += kg; }
        cb -= db; if (cb <= 0){ cb += n; b += kb; }
    }
}

void DrawTriangle(const Point2D& p0, const Point2D& p1, const Point2D& p2)
{
    TriangleLine(p0, p1);
    TriangleLine(p1, p2);
    TriangleLine(p2, p0);

    int y0, y1; // min and max y
    y0 = p0.y; if (y0 > p1.y) y0 = p1.y; if (y0 > p2.y) y0 = p2.y;
    y1 = p0.y; if (y1 < p1.y) y1 = p1.y; if (y1 < p2.y) y1 = p2.y;

    int x0, z0, r0, g0, b0;
    int x1, z1, r1, g1, b1;
    int dx;
    int kz, kr, kg, kb;
    int dz, dr, dg, db;
    int z, cz;
    int r, cr;
    int g, cg;
    int b, cb;

    for (int y = y0; y <= y1; ++y)
    {
        if (ContourX[y][0] < ContourX[y][1])
        {
            x0 = ContourX[y][0];
            z0 = ContourZ[y][0];
            r0 = ContourR[y][0];
            g0 = ContourG[y][0];
            b0 = ContourB[y][0];

            x1 = ContourX[y][1];
            z1 = ContourZ[y][1];
            r1 = ContourR[y][1];
            g1 = ContourG[y][1];
            b1 = ContourB[y][1];
        }
        else
        {
            x1 = ContourX[y][0];
            z1 = ContourZ[y][0];
            r1 = ContourR[y][0];
            g1 = ContourG[y][0];
            b1 = ContourB[y][0];

            x0 = ContourX[y][1];
            z0 = ContourZ[y][1];
            r0 = ContourR[y][1];
            g0 = ContourG[y][1];
            b0 = ContourB[y][1];
        }

        dx = x1 - x0;

        kz = 0; dz = z1 - z0; if (dz > 0) kz = 1; if (dz < 0) { kz = -1; dz = -dz; }
        kr = 0; dr = r1 - r0; if (dr > 0) kr = 1; if (dr < 0) { kr = -1; dr = -dr; }
        kg = 0; dg = g1 - g0; if (dg > 0) kg = 1; if (dg < 0) { kg = -1; dg = -dg; }
        kb = 0; db = b1 - b0; if (db > 0) kb = 1; if (db < 0) { kb = -1; db = -db; }

        z = z0; cz = dx;
        r = r0; cr = dx;
        g = g0; cg = dx;
        b = b0; cb = dx;

        // x<x1 to follow top left rule (ie. don't draw bottom or right edges)
        for (int x = x0; x < x1; ++x)
        {
            SetPixel(x, y, z, r, g, b);

            cz -= dz; if (cz <= 0) { cz += dx; z += kz; }
            cr -= dr; if (cr <= 0) { cr += dx; r += kr; }
            cg -= dg; if (cg <= 0) { cg += dx; g += kg; }
            cb -= db; if (cb <= 0) { cb += dx; b += kb; }
        }
    }
}

int main(void)
{
    // clear the screen
    std::fill(pixels, pixels + SIZE, 0);
    std::fill(zDepth, zDepth + SIZE, 0);
/*
    Point2D p0, p1, p2, p3;

    p0.x = 30;
    p0.y = 41;
    p0.r = 255;
    p0.g = 0;
    p0.b = 0;

    p1.x = 350;
    p1.y = 41;
    p1.r = 0;
    p1.g = 255;
    p1.b = 0;

    p2.x = 40;
    p2.y = 311;
    p2.r = 0;
    p2.g = 0;
    p2.b = 255;

    p3.x = 572;
    p3.y = 280;
    p3.r = 255;
    p3.g = 140;
    p3.b = 0;

    DrawTriangle(p0, p1, p2);
    DrawTriangle(p1, p2, p3);
*/

    Point2D p0, p1, p2, p3, p4, p5;

    p0.x = 10;
    p0.y = 50;
    p0.z = 10;
    p0.zInv = 0xfffff / p0.z;
    p0.r = 255;
    p0.g = 0;
    p0.b = 0;

    p1.x = 400;
    p1.y = 100;
    p1.z = 10;
    p1.zInv = 0xfffff / p1.z;
    p1.r = 255;
    p1.g = 0;
    p1.b = 0;

    p2.x = 290;
    p2.y = 380;
    p2.z = 10;
    p2.zInv = 0xfffff / p2.z;
    p2.r = 255;
    p2.g = 0;
    p2.b = 0;

    DrawTriangle(p0, p1, p2);

    p3.x = 50;
    p3.y = 350;
    p3.z = 2;
    p3.zInv = 0xfffff / p3.z;
    p3.r = 0;
    p3.g = 255;
    p3.b = 0;

    p4.x = 130;
    p4.y = 40;
    p4.z = 20;
    p4.zInv = 0xfffff / p4.z;
    p4.r = 0;
    p4.g = 255;
    p4.b = 0;

    p5.x = 380;
    p5.y = 200;
    p5.z = 5;
    p5.zInv = 0xfffff / p5.z;
    p5.r = 0;
    p5.g = 255;
    p5.b = 0;

    DrawTriangle(p3, p4, p5);

    SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_EVERYTHING);

    SDL_Window* window = SDL_CreateWindow
    (
        "Trig",
        SDL_WINDOWPOS_UNDEFINED,
        SDL_WINDOWPOS_UNDEFINED,
        SCREEN_WIDTH,
        SCREEN_HEIGHT,
        SDL_WINDOW_SHOWN
    );

    SDL_Renderer* renderer = SDL_CreateRenderer(window, -1, SDL_RENDERER_ACCELERATED);
    SDL_Texture* texture = SDL_CreateTexture(renderer, SDL_PIXELFORMAT_BGRA32, SDL_TEXTUREACCESS_STREAMING, SCREEN_WIDTH, SCREEN_HEIGHT);
    SDL_Event event;

    bool quit = false;

    while (!quit)
    {
        if (SDL_PollEvent(&event))
        {
            switch (event.type)
            {
            case SDL_QUIT:
            {
                quit = true;
                break;
            }
            }
        }

        SDL_UpdateTexture(texture, NULL, &pixels[0], SCREEN_WIDTH * 4);
        SDL_RenderCopy(renderer, texture, NULL, NULL);
        SDL_RenderPresent(renderer);
    }

    SDL_DestroyRenderer(renderer);
    SDL_DestroyWindow(window);
    SDL_Quit();

    return 0;
}
```

Unfortunately I didn't get the output I desired

[image]

it should look like this (I used floating point arithmetic with naive z-buffer implementation)

[image]

For reference, here is the output by OpenGL:

[image: 3]

I am not sure what might be the problem. Maybe I need to decrease the step size for 1/z? Any pointers?

Comment: @TedLyngmo I already tried that and I noticed that step sizes for 1/z values for the green triangle seem to be big. I am not sure what is wrong with how I handled 1/z values...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

first using `zInv=0xFFFF/z` on 16bit int might be a problem as you forgot the sign is there too. I would use `zInv=0x7FFF/z` just to be safe. In case `int` is 32 or 64 bit on your platform/compiler then you're fine.

Other than that from a quick look at your code I do not see anything wrong with it. So it might be just problem with precision as `1/z` is highly nonlinear.

To test it you can use 32bit ints for the `zInv` like `zInv=0x7FFFFFFF/z` if the behavior changes (for the better) you know its precision. Beware you have to make sure all the variables along the interpolation of `zInv` is 32bit too.

Another option to test is change the `zInv` to float if that helps a lot you know its precision (IIRC OpenGL also uses floats for this).

To help with precsion you might offset the `z` a bit to move from problematic part of `1/z` (where `|z|` is small) for example:

```
zInv=0x7FFF/(z+z0)
```

so you do not divide by too small values... try for example `z0=1000` if your view direction is `+z` ...

Comment: Thank you very much! I managed to find constants to get the desired output: `0xffffff/(z+1000)`. I’m not sure if it will work for all cases though.

Comment: @JimmyYang if it work near camera then it will definately work further away , just be sure to properly handle case when `z+1000` overflows your int datatype, either clip or have the `1000` as function of z ... The bigger value you chose instead of `1000` the better precision near camera (far away is less precision but only very slightly) also the bigger the `0xFFFFFF` the more precision however beware of overflows during operations on such values ...

Answer (score 0):

You are interpolating the invZ values linearly. But 1/z is not a line. Try computing 1/z for every pixel and compare that with your invZ.

Comment: I see. I've always thought that 1/z is linear. So that means if I use orthographic projection, z is linear and 1/z is not however if I use perspective projection, 1/z is linear and z is not, right?

Comment: No. I don't think 1/z is ever linear. And I think if you use anything but parallel projection then z isn't linear either.

Comment: `1/z` is only visually linear (in perspective views) but the values itselfs are not see [How to correctly linearize depth in OpenGL ES in iOS?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42515399/2521214)

Comment: @Spektre Put your nose touching the monitor in the middel. Now the left border of the monitor has a 1/z of ~0.1 as has the right border. So the above code draws all pixels with a 1/z of 0.1. But at your nose 1/z = 1. Clearly not linear. In perspective views flat surfaces are not flat after the perspective transformation and the graph for 1/z is a curve and not a line on top. You can calculate 1/z every few pixels and interpolate between them fairly well but not over large distances. Games used to calculate 1/z every 8 pixel or so and using a fast inverse approximation. That was good enough.

Comment: @GoswinvonBrederlow the `1/z` is linear visually that means if you render inclined plane with `1/z` depth steps (or color gradient) then after applying the perspective the transformed result will  have the same visual step like on this [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QyWgu.png) but the values of original depth are non linear at all. Once you linearly interpolate between such values the precision is greatly affected by the fact which part of `1/z` it is the closet the `z` to zero the worse it gets ...

Comment: @Spektre Nor sure how you get that result but render my example. A rectangle `(-10, -10, 1) - (10, 10, 1)`. It 's white on the outsides going to black in the center in concentric circles. And the code does a linear interpolation from top to bottom and then side to side so it would be all the same color.