# How to visualize planes in Qt with C++

Tags: c++, qt, model, 3d, viewer

I am with dataset of points and me questions is.
How to show its?

This points are part of a 3D model.
I have them on groups of planes.

I mean, I have all points that are part of a plane.
Then If I join all planes, I have a 3D model like [Hexagon3D](https://github.com/ivanoterouvigo/gbxml/blob/master/imgs/pentagono_001.png):

[image: img]

I can see it with sketchUp. This is a file in xml format.

So, I have data of model in virtual dataset in code and I can see data of this model of a .xml that is output of me Qt, c++ application.

I would like to integrate any viewer in my application but I don't know what are the best tecnology.

Could you suggest anything??

I hear talk about opengl, webgl and other libraries like cgal.

Thanks

Comment: tool / lib recommendations are off topic here so +Close. Use what are you familiar with ...  or have no trouble with on your platform. From your description it is not clear if you got mesh in form of faces or in form of constructive geometry representation. (the points are vertexes of polygon or you need to compute the union of planes instead?). These two are very different ....

Comment: But the 3 main techno:ogies used for 3D in Qt are Qt3D, QtCanvas3D and QOpenGL, try them and use whatever suits you best.

Comment: Hi Spektre, well, I will try to explain it more. I have 3D points and they are vertexex of surface store in a vector of points. I have only stored points but it isn't work to get a store of surfaces, I think it is the same of you name mesh. Then I don't need to compute the union of planes. I need only show points and paint each surface that are parto of 3DModel.

Comment: Hi Dimitri, I will try to know more about Qt3D, QtCanvas3D and QOpenGL.  Could you type any sample of show points or surface with each tecnology.

Comment: Well if the **Vertex**es (points)   are edges of each polygons then you can use any 3D rendering api. My favorite is **OpenGL**. The Mesh should be in boundary representation (contains polygons covering whole surface) and polygons itself should be convex. If not you need to triangulate them first and then render. The version of OpenGL depends on what platform/machines you want to do this because the moder stuff works properly only on nVidia and AMD cards so if you want to use intel or even other graphics you can hit a wall really fast. (in such case GL 1.0 should work everywhere) .

Comment: anyway for 3D gfx you should grasp [Understanding 4x4 homogenous transform matrices](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28084380/2521214) and [simple 3D graphics pipeline](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21100338/2521214) for rendering and setting contexts use google there are tons of tutorial out there for almost each api.