# What is the order of computations in 3D rendering with Matrix multiplication

Tags: matrix, 3d, pipeline, clipping, plane

What is the exact order/ steps to do in order to transform 3D world coordinates to 2D screen coordinates. I have done the two matrix multiplications with the ViewMatrix and the ProjectionMatrix. I check with the "w" value if a point is behind the near-clipping plane of the view frustum, but I don't understand how to react to this statement. Which type of coordinates do I get with clipping and what do I do next with these coordinates. Thank you for your answers.

Comment: see [Mathematically compute a simple graphics pipeline](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21100338/2521214)

Comment: After mutiplying by the projection matrix you are in clip space. Checkout wikipedia article on clip space: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clip_coordinates