# Where is the screen positioned in 3d projection analysis?

Tags: graphics, 3d, projection

I heard of an analysis of 3D projection like this:

You are the camera, wachting through a window (the screen), through which you see the 3D world. I'm not sure if this analysis is correct and I'm having trouble understanding where the screen or this imaginary 'window' is placed.

Let say, camera is positioned at (0,0,0) and the znear plane at (0,0,0.1). Is the screen then positioned between the camera and the znear plane (0 - 0.1 on z-axis)?

If anybody can give me a better analysis so I can understand it better, it would be very helpfull!

I couldn't find clear answers on google or ai bot.Constantly getting confused

Comment: your wording "3d projection analysis" is quite misleading take a look at: [Mathematically compute a simple graphics pipeline](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21100338/2521214) the projection plane (your screen/window) is placed at `znear` plane and its position depends on projection matrix used usually its centered around `(0,0,0)` or `(0,0,-l)` or `(0,0,+l)`where `l` is focal length of the projection (distance between `focus` and `znear`) the polarity depends on direction you looking for example `gluPerspecive` is using `-Z` axis viewing direction ...